# Python Anywhere Django App Import Error

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm getting the following import error when trying to run a django app on Python Anywhere:

```
Error running WSGI application
ImportError: No module named 'chamberlin.settings'
  File "/var/www/mikechamberlin_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 58, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have checked both my WSGI config file and my directory structure and both seem to be correct.

WSGI File:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/mikechamberlin/chamberlin'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'chamberlin.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Tree:

```
mikechamberlin
├── ...
├── chamberlin
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── chamberlin
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── private_settings.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── static
    ...
```

Can anyone see something I'm not seeing? I've already searched here and read the ImportError help messages on PythonAnywhere, but my things seem to be named correctly. Importing from the console works, but I still get this error when trying to run the application.

Much Appreciated.

Comment: Where the `wsgi.py` is located. Show it in the tree please.

Comment: The tree is quite large, but the wsgi file is located at

`/var/www/(domain)_wsgi.py`

The above tree is located at

`/home/mikechamberlin/chamberlin`

Comment: Are you saying that the `wsgi.py` is located outside of `chamberlin/` dir?

Comment: Oh, no. Sorry. It's in `home/mikechamberlin/chamberlin/chamberlin`

Comment: So, it is on the same level as `settings.py`, `private_settings.py` etc ?

Comment: Yes. It's in the same dir as `settings.py`

Comment: In that case, change to this: `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'`. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Same error. The import works from the console, but not when the server tries to handle a request for some reason.

Comment: Then I believe you should contact `PythonAnywhere` staff, to inspect your problem and guide you.

Comment: You should also be able to set the path in the pythonanywhere webapps tab to /home/mikechamberlin/chamberlin instead of doing this in the wsgi.py file

Comment: You have to do both. The path in the webapp page is set to the parent folder of the project, but the WSGI configuration file still has to set the environment variable `"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"` to point to settings.py

Comment: You may be getting module aliasing going on. Try changing the `sys.path.append(path)` to `sys.path.insert(0, path)`so that your settings module is first in `sys.path`

Comment: ^^100% fixed. Thanks, Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same struggle while deploying on pythonanywhere before but, I try all possible combinations to exposing the location of my settings.py.

```
import os 
import sys

path = '/home/garapkan/Garap/garap_v2/'
print(path)

if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.insert(0, path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler

application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

and make sure the path is in the first oreder of sys.path insert it at first row instead of append it. read @glenn comment on question.
and I found it works for me. Hope this way will work for others too.